# Openvpn via network-manager using 2fA overwrites saved password

Tags: xubuntu, network-manager, 19.04, openvpn

I am setting up 2FA on our openvpn connections and while it is all working fine on ubuntu 19.04 with network manager, it over writes the saved password with the google authenticator code, so the next connection fails until the password and the authenticator code are entered.

Is there any way to prevent the saved password from being clobbered?

Not found it yet.

Comment: Happens with Ubuntu 18.04.3 as well and it's super annoying.

Comment: I'm also getting this on 20.04 :-(

Comment: Known incompatibility.  Network Manager has not moved on this yet.

Answer (score 1):

About a month back, I posted that the bug *HAS* been reported, but has had no activity. But that was moderated away.

The bug report can be found at:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/97

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review – Merlijn Sebrechts Aug 14 at 20:12

I'm not sure what additional detail there is to provide beyond the fact the bug has been reported.

Some searching shows that it has been reported: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1787956

Answer (score 0):

Just make the file where the passwords are stored immutable

```
sudo chattr +i ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```

If you want to add another VPN in the future, make the file temporarily mutable by changing the `+i` flag to `-i`

Comment: I am not a keyring expert but it seems like your solution will block ANY change to the keyring login file, so it's not just VPN's it's any login details, isn't it?

Comment: @Wazime You are right, this will block ANY change to the keyring file. If you need to do something that makes changes to the keyring file, you will have to execute the `chattr` command again with `-i` flag, do the thing and then make it immutable again with `+i`. Its not great, but it works.